# Will adding a class without style information cause reflow?

Tags: html, css, dom, reflow

Will adding a class without any associated style information (e.g. no CSS entry for the class) cause a reflow or some other significant synchronous processing? Would the answer apply to most browsers, or only e.g. older browsers?

I did try to run an experiment with FF performance monitor, but I'm not proficient enough to interpret the results; the waterfall does show a layout after adding a class, but I'm unable to draw any real conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It will cause a style application *invalidation*, but when the browser performs a re-evaluation it will see that the element's *computed properties* that affect layout have not been altered, so it won't trigger a layout - or even a repaint.

Remember that different CSS properties may trigger a relayout when changed (such as `width`), others only trigger a repaint (such as `background-color`), and others do nothing at all (such as `voice-family`, which is in the (now obsolete) Aural module which is independent of the *visual*-formatting model).